# Split string with a different expression

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, split

I'm in need to split an string, but using an expression `"},{"` and not just one char, like I've seen on another questions. This is the string I want to separate:

```
{"Id":"620e1fe3f6f0b48fd385edebdc5896e4865d0c8a1a49ca24b9f8b08a4a1bc17e","Names":["/delete2alpine"],"Image":"alpine","Command":"/bin/sh"},{"Id":"dfc8494f4b9cc3a409a01032906431b54a2d88bb06b4fed26ede0eb8a37c41a9","Names":["/deletealpine"],"Image":"alpine","Command":"/bin/sh"}
```

I wanted to separate it into the `"},{"`, I've tried using the `String.split()`; and it just returns me a wrong array.

Comment: How your final output should look like ?

Comment: `String.split()` accepts a regex as a parameter, so something like `s.split("},\\{")` should do the trick.

Comment: The string that you are working with resembles a lot like a JSON String. Why not parse that string as with a regular JSON Parser ?

Answer (score 1):

`String.split()` takes a regex argument, and your desired delimiter `},{` contains special characters for regex. You need to quote your delimiter as follows:

```
str.split(Pattern.quote("},{"));
```

This requires importing Pattern:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also double escape openening curly brace:

```
str.split("},\\{");
```

If you don't escape the opening curly brace it's meaning would be the start if a [repetition](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

[Test](http://rextester.com/SLIWJ52897)